# how did etherscan displays pending transaction?

Tags: etherscan

since eth_pendingTransaction endpoint is no longer supported and cannot be found here
https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API

how does etherscan listens and display for pending transaction? does it use filters, websockets, etc?

Comment: `txpool.Content()` is your friend

Comment: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"txpool_content","params":[],"id":67}'  http://localhost:8545/`

Comment: after enabling `txpool` module, something like: `--http.api 'eth,net,web3,txpool,debug'` in `geth` options

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan runs its own customised nodes and infrastructure, much of its functionality is not directly available in open source projects.